# How to print number of blocks in a region in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, blocks, media, theming

I use Drupal 6 and I'm trying to get number of blocks in a region. How is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query returns the number of blocks in the *left* region of the current theme.
Replace *left* with your region name.

```
$current_theme = variable_get('theme_default', '');
$number_of_blocks = db_result(db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {blocks} WHERE theme='%s' AND region='%s'", $current_theme, 'left'));
```